# allocate mbuf with external data buffer

Tags: sockets, freebsd, bsd

I am writing an ethernet driver for a bsd ip-stack. I am allocating mbuf as follows:

`MGETHDR (m, M_NOWAIT, MT_DATA);
 MCLGET (m, M_NOWAIT);`

mbuf can have m_data pointed to an external independent buffer and flag M_EXT activated, is there a BSD api to allocate memory for this external buffer and have the recent m (mbuf) pointing to that external buffer?